# jQuery - Search in Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, search

Assume I have an Array of jQuery objects. I would like to search in array and find out such a key exists are not.
NOTE: The objects are not of same pattern

Ex:

```
a = [  { "chart_type" : 4}, 
       { "x_axis" : { "field_type" : 5, "name" : "priority" } },
       { "y_axis" : { "field_type" : 3, "name" : "created_at" }}

    ]
```

I would like to search from the above, if key such as "chart_type" exists or not. If yes, I would like to get the value.

```
a.find("chart_type").value // Need something like this
```

I tried the following.

```
jQuery.grep(chart_hash, function(key,value){
    if(key == "chart_type")
      return value
     });
```

However, the above doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: check this link  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery.each](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
$.each(chart_hash, function(index,value){

    $.each(value,function(key,val){
         if(key == "chart_type")
          return val
         });
     })

})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it doesnt work for me. My array contains jQuery object. So when i loop through, I am getting the 'key' to be index and 'value ' as object.